# CASE/IF with cast

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I keep having an error and I don't understand why, I hope you can help me. I want to condition the following expression :

```
CAST((pwdLastSet0 / 864000000000.0 - 109207) AS DATETIME) AS 'PasswordLastSet',dateadd(d, 80, CAST((pwdLastSet0 / 864000000000.0 - 109207) as DATETIME)) AS 'expirationdate'
```

Because, if my column value pwdlastset0 is null, the calculation can't be done.

So, I tried both shapes :

```
case 
    when pwdlastset0 !=0
    then
CAST((pwdLastSet0 / 864000000000.0 - 109207) AS DATETIME) AS [Password Last Set],dateadd(d, 80, CAST((pwdLastSet0 / 864000000000.0 - 109207) as DATETIME)) AS 'futurdate'
    else
pwslastset0 = 'The password has never been set'
```

and

```
If pwdlastset0 !=0
then
CAST((pwdLastSet0 / 864000000000.0 - 109207) AS DATETIME) AS [Password Last Set],dateadd(d, 80, CAST((pwdLastSet0 / 864000000000.0 - 109207) as DATETIME)) AS 'futurdate'
else
pwdlastset0 = 'The password has never been set'
```

I tried without the "AS" and also to change my condition, I mean, if = 0 then show 'not set yet' else calucation. Anyway I can't get it to work so if any of you have an idea for something I didn't try yet, thank you very much !

Comment: I just kep the dateadd function and it worked...

Answer (score 3):

`pwdlastset0 !=0` does not check for `NULL`. Use `IS NULL` expression:

```
case 
    when pwdlastset0 IS NOT NULL
    then
CAST((pwdLastSet0 / 864000000000.0 - 109207) AS DATETIME) AS [Password Last Set],dateadd(d, 80, CAST((pwdLastSet0 / 864000000000.0 - 109207) as DATETIME)) AS 'futurdate'
    else
pwslastset0 = 'The password has never been set'
```

Comment: HI, thank you for the answer I should have think about that ! Anyway I keep having an error due to the CAST...

Comment: @MartinVincent maybe, you use wrong data type for `pwdlastset0 `

Comment: I have the correct result if I add a "where pwdlastset != 0" but I'd also like to show pwdlast = 0 as 'pwd has never been set'

Answer (score 0):

Change your comparison to check if the pwdlastset0 is greater than 0.  If it is not greater than 0, it will return password has never been set.

```
case 
    when pwdlastset0 > 0
    then
CAST((pwdLastSet0 / 864000000000.0 - 109207) AS DATETIME) AS [Password Last Set],dateadd(d, 80, CAST((pwdLastSet0 / 864000000000.0 - 109207) as DATETIME)) AS 'futurdate'
    else
pwslastset0 = 'The password has never been set'
```